# Solve the equation: $x^{1/(1+\log x)}=10^3$

Tags: logarithms

> Solve the equation: $x^{1/(1+\log x)}=10^3$.

I thought to take the logarithm on both sides but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: For $\log$ you mean base $10$ or base $e$?

Comment: I mean base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by $\log(x)$ you mean $\log_{10}(x)$. Taking $\log_{10}$ on both sides, we obtain
$$\dfrac1{1+\log_{10}(x)} \cdot \log_{10}(x) = \log_{10}\left(10^3\right) = 3$$
Rearranging this, gives us
$$\log_{10}(x) = 3 + 3\log_{10}(x) \implies \log_{10}(x) = -\dfrac32 \implies x = 10^{-3/2} = \dfrac1{10\sqrt{10}}$$

Comment: I don't understand how did you het from taking $log_10$ on both sides that expression on the left

Comment: @era Use the rule $\log(a^b) = b \cdot \log (a)$.

Comment: @rwols, ok thanks, now I get it all.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{1/(1+\log x)}=10^3$$

$$\log(x^{1/(1+\log x)})=\log(10^3)$$

$${\log(x) \over {1+\log(x)}}=3\log(10)=3$$
$$\log(x)=3 (1+\log(x))$$
$$\log(x)=3 +3\log(x)$$
$$-2\log(x)=3$$
$$\log(x)=-\frac{3}{2}$$
$$x=10^{-{3 \over 2}}$$

Comment: You might want to use `\log`, `\exp` and `\left( \right)` to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

let us make a change of variable $$\log_{10}x = a, x = 10^a.$$ with that we have $$x^{\frac1{1+a}} = 10^3\to \frac1{1+a}\log_{10}x= 3,\frac{a}{1+a} = 3$$

solving for $a,$  we find that $$a = -2/3 \to x = 10^{-2/3}=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{100}}$$